# How to minimize size of scrollview after hiding UI elements inside in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-scrollview

I have a `ScrollView` and i'm hiding some UI Elements inside by calling

```
suffixSpinner.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
serviceLineTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
subscriberIdTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
suffixTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

This creates white space in the `ScrollView` where the UI elements once were.
How do I remove that white space and minimize the `ScrollView` to fit again?

Answer (score 1):

We have to way to hide view in android

**First** `View.INVISIBLE`  This view is invisible, but it still takes up space for layout purposes.

**Second**  `View.GONE` This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout purposes.

**View.INVISIBLE**

[image]

**View.GONE**

[image]

Replace Code With This:

```
suffixSpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
serviceLineTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
subscriberIdTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
suffixTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: This solution is really explanatory, should work for you. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

use `View.GONE` instead. `View.INVISIBLE` will still take up the required space in the view.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at doc
[View.Gone](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#GONE)
[View.INVISIBLE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#INVISIBLE)

> View.GONE This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout purposes.
>
> View.INVISIBLE This view is invisible, but it still takes up space for layout purposes.